# Using IAR Embedded Workbench to configure an Arduino Due through J-link, the debugger never reaches the main function of my C-Code

Tags: c, iar, arduino-due, segger-jlink

IAR Embedded Workbench 9.40
J-link EDU
Arduino Due
Programming in C

The script works on my friend's computer, but not on mine. The connection to J-link and Arduino CPU appear to work correctly.
However, the debugger never reaches the main part of my script.
I have at one point gotten it to run, only once. and I cannot recreate it.

There is no warning or error message.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be the problem?
Here is a pixely video of me trying to set a break-point in my main function.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9wvcCZCgRA

Thank you!

Reinstalled IAR Embedded Workbench
Reinstalled J-link Drivers
Reset Arduino
Tried a different computer (which worked), this computer ran a slightly older version of IAR

Answer (score 0):

For now, changing the linker configuration file from "sram.icf" to "flash.icf" seems to have fixed the issue.
I'm not sure what this implies for the rest of the system.

Comment: Linker configuration file is for memory placement. I don't know what your files contain, but from names I would guess that *sram.icf* is for running program code from ram, and *flash.icf* from flash. Typically running from ram is harder, because you need to make sure that program code is correctly transferred to ram from either flash or by debugger before startup. That is why code running directly from flash is usually the normal way to do it in embedded systems.